# How to build stagefright-plugins for Android in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-ndk, stagefright

I tried compile stagefright-plugins for Android in Ubuntu ( https://github.com/omxcodec/stagefright-plugins) but i have a problem with step:

```
    you should merge my android_frameworks_native(branch: cm_maguro-10.1) and
   android_frameworks_av(branch: cm_maguro-10.1) code. once you do, you should pay attention to
   the "USES_NAM" flag, it is only in the "android/frameworks/native" and "android/frameworks/av"
   directories.
```

I can not find "USES_NAM" flag in the "android/frameworks/native" and "android/frameworks/av" directories. Also I can not see "android/frameworks/native" and "android/frameworks/av"  directories. 
Could you please help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance